# <?php wp_head(); ?> = FIXO ao rolar o scroll no wordpress?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Fala galera, queria saber como eu posso fazer com que meu menu fique fixo quando rolasse o scroll do navegador, independente do tema que estou usando, até pq estou usando um tema free da Customify e vi que ele não me da essa possibilidade, só a versão pro e queria fazer isso via código msm.

Comment: Via CSS, colcoando posistion:fixed. Mas isso pode trazer outros problemas ao seu layout. Tem esse plugin, teste: https://wordpress.org/plugins/fixed-and-sticky-header/

Comment: Sim, via CSS eu sei que dá, queria algo mais específico e próprio do wordpress, se possível (usando o menu que já estou usando), msm assim, agradeço seu apoio!

Comment: Problema resolvido. Descobri um plugin que havia usado um tempo atrás e tinha esquecido dele. O nome do plugin é "myStickymenu". Com ele consigo colocar qualquer menu para a função "sticky" ao rolar o scroll do navegador! ;D

Answer (score 0):

tente ir até o seu editor de CSS  do wp, e adicione o seguinte codigo:

```html
.site-header{
position:fixed;
}
```